# Warning: file_put_contents - cannot create file using php

Tags: php, createfile

When I am trying to do this:

```
$txt = file_get_contents('http://stats.pingdom.com/file'); 
file_put_contents('/stats/file.html',$txt);
```

I am getting following error:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(stats/stats.html) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/jtf/public_html/index.php on line 2
```

the folder stats is `777`

what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

`/stats` and `stats` (or the equivalent, `./stats`) are not necessarily the same directory (in fact they might refer to the same directory only in theory). Most likely you are currently trying to write to a directory that does not even exist.

So this should work:

```
file_put_contents('stats/file.html',$txt); // removed "/" prefix
```

Comment: I believe you mean: "So this should work [if the stats directory exists]"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$txt = file_get_contents('http://stats.pingdom.com/file');
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/stats/file.html', $txt);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `/stats/` folder in the root directory on your server, I believe.

Note the `/home/jtf/public_html/` path. You have to use this one to address files in the document root of your web-server.

Answer (score 0):

Your path points to `/` instead to `/home/jtf/public_html/`
Just use `../`